# Correct approach to override DetailsRow styling

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webpack, office-ui-fabric

What would be the *correct* way to override the styling of the Office UI Fabric DetailsRow component?

I mean, this component does not expose anything like `className` in its props, so it does not seem to be possible to append any custom class names to the row's root element within an `onRenderRow` override, well, unless one fully re-writes the row rendering code.

Of course I could fall back to a dirty hack and use something like

```
ms-DetailsRow: hover {
    background-color: #cbcbcb !important;
}
```

in my own CSS file that is loaded after Office Fabric UI styles, but that does not look like a clean solution to me.

Comment: Now I figured out that I can use something like loadStyles('.root_f418bb43:hover { background-color: "[theme:themeLighter, default: #deecf9]" '); but that still concerns me as class names such as "root_f418bb43" are "reverse engineered" and can change in future versions of Office UI Fabris.

Comment: You should try to post the question into github of the project. They are more responsive and active over there. [Office UI Fabric Core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core/issues) and [Office UI Fabric JS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/issues)